# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}.$ $f$ is a constant function?

Comment: Are you asking if $f$ must be a constant function, or if a constant function satisfies the criterion?

Comment: @jbowman: Undoubtedly the former.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: One hopes so, but I've been surprised a time or two!

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f'(x)$ exists on $\mathbb{R}$, and if $f'$ is discontinuous at $x=a$, then it must be an *essential* discontinuity.  That is, there cannot be a jump discontinuity there.  But I'm having trouble making that into a proof that $f$ has to be constant.

Comment: This question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151931/set-of-zeroes-of-the-derivative-of-a-pathological-function

Comment: $f'$ maps a set of irrational numbers to an interval.

Answer (score 29):

No, such a function is not necessarily constant.

At the bottom of page 351 of [*Everywhere Differentiable, Nowhere Monotone Functions*](http://web.archive.org/web/20170930042605/http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?4,file=8103,filename=katznelson-stromberg.pdf), Katznelson and Stromberg give the following theorem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Then there exists an everywhere differentiable function $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
>
> - $F'(a) = 1$ for all $a \in A$,
> - $F'(b) < 1$ for all $b \in B$,
> - $0 < F'(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Choosing $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and an arbitrary (nonempty*) countable set $B \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, we get an everywhere differentiable function $F$ with $F'(q) = 1$ when $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.  So if we define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = F(x) - x$, this then is the desired function satisfying $f'(q) = F'(q) - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f$ is not constant (or else its derivative would be zero everywhere by the mean value theorem).

*(in case you take "countable" to mean either "countably infinite" or "finite")