# Is a function whose derivative vanishes at rationals constant?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to make a problem for my advanced calculus students.  I was thinking, if we have a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(q)=0$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, can we say that $f$ is constant?

Comment: I do think it is a constant function.

Comment: Suppose not, then there is a neighbourhood of some x such that $\|f(y)\|>a$ for all y in the neighbourhood.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative

Comment: (Original article here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01449201)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161733/let-f-mathbbr-longrightarrow-mathbbr-a-differentiable-function-such-that

Comment: Derivatives can be very pathological.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_question_mark_function#Properties_of_.3F.28x.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ doesn't have to be constant!

A non-constant function $f$ with the required properties is given as Exercise 13.J in A. C. M. van Rooij, W. H. Schikhof, [A Second Course on Real Functions](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=A.%20C.%20M.%20van%20Rooij,%20W.%20H.%20Schikhof&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=A.%20C.%20M.%20van%20Rooij%2C%20W.%20H.%20Schikhof&f=false), based on an example due to Y. Katznelson and Karl Stromberg, in *Everywhere differentiable, nowhere monotone, functions*, Amer. Math. Monthly 81 (1974), 349–354, [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318996?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Here is a copy of the example:

[image: c1]

[image: c2]

[image: c3]

[image: c4]

---

Another example is has been constructed by Dimitrie Pompeiu in *Sur les fonctions dérivées*, Math. Ann. 63 (1907), no. 3, 326—332, doi: [10.1007/BF01449201](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01449201), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/158291), [GDZ](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN0022614050).

You can have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative).

Comment: The wikipedia article states that there are nonconstant differentiable functions whose derivate vanishes on a dense set - how can we guarantee that the rational numbers are contained in this set?

Comment: @Dominik : I agree, this doesn't need to be the case. But the example given in A. C. M. van Rooij, W. H. Schikhof exactly satisfies the condition $f'(x) = 0$ for all rational $x$.

Comment: Why give this complicated example when the the Pompeiu example, which is proved at the link you gave (thanks), is simpler and is a direct answer to the question of the OP?

Comment: @zhw. : AFAIK, in the Pompeiu example, the derivative vanishes on some dense subset (of a closed interval) – as pointed out by Dominik above –, so it doesn't answer completely the OP's request.

Comment: No, the wiki. article deals specifically with the rationals in $[0,1].$ (And it doesn't matter; it can be any countable subset of $[0,1].$) Let $f$ be this function. Then $f'(0)=f'(1) =0.$ So we can extend this $f$ to $[0,2]$ as follows: For $x\in [1,2],$ let $f(x) = f(x-1) + f(1)-f(0).$ Now we have a differentiable $f$ strictly increasing on $[0,2]$ such that $f'(q)=0$ for each rational $q\in [0,2].$ We can continue this to the right or left to obtain a strictly increasing differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ whose derivative equals $0$ at each rational $q\in \mathbb R.$

Comment: @zhw: But the construction from the wikipedia article yields a function whose derivative vanishes in the points $g(p_i)$, where $p_i$ are the rationals in $[0, 1]$. It is not clear why the derivative should also vanish in the $p_i$.

Comment: @Dominik Ah, I see. I glossed over that, my bad. Thanks to you and Watson for the correction.