# Set of points of non-differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

As an exercise I proved that if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function then the set of discontinuities of $f$ must be an $F_\sigma$ set. I thought it was an interesting result.

Now I am wondering: is there a result like this for points of non-differentiability of $f$? If $N_f$ denotes the set of points where $f$ is not differentiable does $N_f$ have to be of a certain type?

Comment: For continuous function $f$, the set of discontinuities $N_f$ is countable union of $G_\delta$'s.

Comment: See my answer to [Continuous functions are differentiable on a measurable set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you. In your answer does "does not have finite derivative" mean the same as "is not differentiable"?

Comment: If so maybe you could post the link to your other answer as an answer here so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked in a comment, I'm posting my comment as an answer.

The answer to your question about $N_f$ is given in my answer to [Continuous functions are differentiable on a measurable set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set).