# Does there exist a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose directional derivatives are infinity in almost every direction, at all points?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

For $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{r}\in S^1$ (here $S^1=\{\mathbf{r}\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|\mathbf{r}\|=1\}$), let us write $f'(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{r})=\infty$ if $\liminf\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{r})-f(\mathbf{x})}{t}=\infty$.

My question is the following: does there exist a (not necessarily measurable) function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the set
$$\{\mathbf{r}\in S^1: f'(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{r})=\infty\text{ or }f'(\mathbf{x};-\mathbf{r})=\infty\}$$
has full measure as a subset of $S^1$? Here $S^1$ is equipped with the "arc length" measure.

[Can a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be "infinitely steep" on a set with non-zero Lebesgue outer measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511847/can-a-function-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-be-infinitely-steep-on-a) tells us that on any line parallell to $\mathbf{r}$, the set of points $\mathbf{x}$ for which $f'(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{r})=\infty\text{ or }f'(\mathbf{x};-\mathbf{r})=\infty$, is a null set. One is then tempted to argue that by Tonelli's, the set

$$A=\{(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{x})\in S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2: f'(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{r})=\infty\text{ or }f'(\mathbf{x};-\mathbf{r})=\infty\}$$
is a null set. On the other hand, Tonelli's seems to imply that when $\{\mathbf{r}\in S^1: f'(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{r})=\infty\text{ or }f'(\mathbf{x};-\mathbf{r})=\infty\}$ has full measure for all $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $A$ has full measure, so there appears to be a contradiction. However, none of these applications of Tonelli are valid, since Tonelli only works when one integrates over a measurable set and a set may be non-measurable even if all of its sections are null sets. Indeed, there are non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which all sections are singletons (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89375/sections-measure-zero-imply-set-is-measure-zero).

All of this is to say, I cannot straightforwardly deduce from the "$1$-dimensional case", i.e. the first link, that that there cannot exist a function with the properties as in my question. My hope is that I have not overlooked some obvious argument here and that either the answer to my question is negative for some "deeper" reason, or, even better, that the answer is affirmative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such function $f.$ The main idea behind this argument is to make use of intersections between different directions.

Restrict $f$ to the open unit circle $B.$ Define sets of directions
\begin{align*}
S_0&:=\{(x,y):0<x<y<4x/3\}\\
S_1&:=\{(-x,y):(x,y)\in D_0\}\\
S_2&:=\{(-x,-y):(x,y)\in D_0\}\\
S_3&:=\{(x,-y):(x,y)\in D_0\}\\
\end{align*}

Define $E_i$ to be the set of $x\in B$ such that there exist $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $r\in S_i$ and $r'\in S_{i+1\pmod 4}$ such that $f'(x,r)=\infty$ and $f'(x,r')=-\infty.$
So points in $E_0$ have some $+\infty$ derivative "up and to the right" and some $-\infty$ derivative "up and to the left".
Considering the possible cases we have $B=\bigcup_{i=0}^3 E_i.$
Therefore there exists $i$ such that $E_i$ has outer measure at least $1/4.$ Composing $f$ with a rotation if necessary, assume $i=0$ works.

Pick $K$ such that the set $E_0\cap \{x:|f(x)|\leq K\}$ has outer measure $>1/5.$ This is justified by countable subadditivity. Define $$A_{j,\epsilon}=\{x:(\exists r\in S_0)(\forall t)0<t<\epsilon\implies (f(x+tr)-f(x))/t>j\\
\wedge(\exists r\in S_1)(\forall t)0<t<\epsilon\implies (f(x+tr)-f(x))/t<-j\}.$$ Pick $\epsilon_1>0$ such that $E_0\cap \{x:|f(x)|\leq K\}\cap A_{1,\epsilon_1}$ has outer measure $>1/5.$ Recursively, for each $k=2,3,\dots$ pick $\epsilon_k>0$ such that $Z_k:=E_0\cap \{x:|f(x)|\leq K\}\cap \bigcap_{j=1}^k A_{j,\epsilon_j}$ has outer measure $>1/5.$ Let $\overline{Z_k}$ denote the closure of $Z_k$ and define $C=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \overline{Z_k}.$ By Fubini's theorem, there exists $y$ such that $C_y:=\{x:(x,y)\in C\}$ has measure at least $1/10.$ Define $g:C_y\to\mathbb R$ by $g(x)=\limsup_{(x',y')\to (x,y)\\(x',y')\in Z_k\\k\to\infty}f(x,y).$

**Lemma.** If $x,x'\in C_y$ and $0<x'-x<\tfrac 3 5\epsilon_k$ then $(g(x')-g(x))/(x'-x)\geq k.$

*Proof.* Let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary. Pick points $z,z'\in Z_k$ within distance $\delta$ of $(x,y)$ and $(x',y)$ respectively and such that $|f(z)-g(x)|<\delta$ and $|f(z')-g(x')|<\delta.$ By definition of $A_{k,\epsilon_k}$ there are directions $r\in S_0$ and $r'\in S_1$ such that $(f(z+tr)-f(z))/t>k$ and $(f(z'+t'r')-f(z'))/t'<-k$ as long as $0<t,t'<\epsilon_k.$
There are unique $t,t'$ with $z+tr=z'+t'r'.$
If I've got the geometry correct, the condition $0<x'-x<\tfrac 3 5\epsilon_k$ gives $0<t,t'<\epsilon_k$ for $\delta$ sufficiently small. Hence $f(z')-f(z)>(t+t')k>(x'-x)k.$ Taking $\delta\to 0$ gives the result. $\square$

So we have a function $g:C_y\to\mathbb R$ with a kind of infinite derivative at each point of $C.$ Extend $g$ to $g':\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by linear interpolation in each connected component of $\mathbb R\setminus C.$ The lower Dini derivatives at each point $x$ are not $-\infty$ - either there is a sequence $x_n\in C$ converging to $x$ from below, so the Lemma gives $(g(x_n)-g(x))/(x_n-x)\to+\infty,$ or there is no such sequence and $g'$ is defined to be an affine function in some interval $(x-\epsilon,x).$ And the upper Dini derivatives are $+\infty$ at each point of $C_y$ that is a two-sided limit. This contradicts the Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem, which says that a.e. point with a $+\infty$ upper left Dini derivative must have a $-\infty$ lower right Dini derivative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I didn’t see it in time to award the bounty. Could you elaborate on why the lower Dini derivatives are never $-\infty$? And in the proof of the lemma, it does seem that you need $f(z) \approx_{\delta} g(x)$ and $f(z’) \approx_{\delta} g(x’)$ and not merely inequality, right? And also (a minor point) you only have $t+t’>x’-x$ when $\delta$ is sufficiently small, right?

Comment: Yes, we want $\delta$ small to guarantee $t,t'>0$