# Is the set of differentiable points of a monotonic function Borel-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotonically increasing function.

Then, it has a countable discontinuity and is differentiable almost everywhere with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Define $D=\{x: f \text{ is differentiable at } x\}$.

I know that $m(D^c)=0$ and $D$ is Lebesgue-measurable. However, I'm curious whether $D$ is Borel-measurable. Is there an example such that $D$ is **not** Borel-measurable?

Comment: In fact, the set of points of finite differentiability of *ANY* function (even a non-Lebesgue measurable function) from the reals to the reals is a $F_{\sigma \delta}$ set, which is Borel measurable in a fairly simple way. See my answer at [Characterization of sets of differentiability](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905083/characterization-of-sets-of-differentiability). See also the answers at [Continuous functions are differentiable on a measurable set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set).