# A question about measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the differentiable point set of a function measurable？

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean differentiable point set? Do you mean the points at which the function is differentiable?

Comment: See [Characterization of sets of differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905083/characterization-of-sets-of-differentiability) AND [Continuous functions are differentiable on a measurable set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set).