# Prove that the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f' \text{ exists}\}$ is Borel whenever $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

**Question**:  Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  Prove that the set of points where the derivative of $f$ exists is Borel measurable.

**My Thoughts**:  So, we are really trying to prove that the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f' \text{ exists}\}$ is open whenever $f$ is continuous. So, if we can show that $A$ is open, then we would be done.  But, I am not sure if I should just play with the definition of differentiability, or if there is something topological I should be considering.

Any help, suggestions, ideas, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: A Borel measurable set is not necessary open. The Borel sigma-algebra is just generated by the open sets.

Comment: Ah, right, so I should be trying more for the countable union of closed or open set tactic?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set

Comment: See also [Characterization of sets of differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905083/13130).